# Unable to fetch values from Spring Cloud Config Server to my Config-Client(limits-service)

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

After days of search over internet and many tries(out of which nothing worked out for me), i am writing here

I have Project- *spring-cloud-config-server* which has following files(full project can be accessed from https://github.com/AshishBharadwaj94/spring-cloud-config-server.git)

- SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.java
- application.properties (under folder- resources)
- Link Source Folder- git-config-repo which has limits-service's properties files
- pom.xml

and Client Config Project- *limits-service* which has following files(full project can be accessed from https://github.com/AshishBharadwaj94/limits-service.git)

- LimitsServiceApplication.java
- LimitConfiguration.java
- Configuration.java
- LimitsConfigurationController.java
- bootstrap.properties (under folder- resources)
- pom.xml

Also project- https://github.com/AshishBharadwaj94/git-config-repo.git

Project- *spring-cloud-config-server* is working fine and has the following output

```
// http://localhost:8888/limits-service/default

{
  "name": "limits-service",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": "8dd340030a5c82a11327bf0d2e55ae3b6434240b",
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "file:///D:/Learn-Java/springboot-workspace/git-config-repo//limits-service.properties",
      "source": {
        "limits-service.minimum": "11",
        "limits-service.maximum": "99"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but when running Project- *limits-service*, i have the following output. It is unable to fetch data from spring-cloud-config-server

```
// http://localhost:8080/limits

{
  "minimum": null,
  "maximum": null
}
```

Below are the files Project wise

**spring-cloud-config-server**

SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.java

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///D:/Learn-Java/springboot-workspace/git-config-repo/
```

spring-cloud-config-server/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-M4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-cloud-config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

limits-service.properties

```
limits-service.minimum=11
limits-service.maximum=99
```

**limits-service**

LimitsServiceApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LimitsServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LimitsServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

LimitConfiguration.java

```
@Component
public class LimitConfiguration {

    private String minimun;
    private String maximun;
    
    public LimitConfiguration() {
        super();
    }
    
    public LimitConfiguration(String minimun, String maximun) {
        super();
        this.minimun = minimun;
        this.maximun = maximun;
    }

    public String getMinimun() {
        return minimun;
    }

    public void setMinimun(String minimun) {
        this.minimun = minimun;
    }

    public String getMaximun() {
        return maximun;
    }

    public void setMaximun(String maximun) {
        this.maximun = maximun;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LimitConfiguration [minimun=" + minimun + ", maximun=" + maximun + "]";
    }

}
```

Configuration.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("limits-service")
public class Configuration {
    
    private String minimum;
    private String maximum;
    
    public String getMinimum() {
        return minimum;
    }
    public void setMinimum(String minimum) {
        this.minimum = minimum;
    }
    public String getMaximum() {
        return maximum;
    }
    public void setMaximum(String maximum) {
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }
    
}
```

LimitsConfigurationController.java

```
@RestController
public class LimitsConfigurationController {
    
    @Autowired
    private Configuration configuration;
    
    @GetMapping(path="/limits")
    public LimitConfiguration retrieveLimitsFromConfiguration() {
        
        return new LimitConfiguration(configuration.getMinimum(), configuration.getMaximum());
    }

}
```

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=limits-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
```

limits-service/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-M4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>limits-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>limits-service</name>
    <description>Build microservices with spring cloud</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes Bootstrap is no longer default in spring cloud 2020.0. You either need to enable bootstrap or use spring.config.import in application.properties. I'll put an answer in later.

Comment: Github link was enough for me to introspect and add in the needful thing. Thank you so much @spencergibb. Per 2020.0 Release Notes, adding the **spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap**  in config-client's pom.xml worked out for me. For others, put the below dependency jar in pom.xml 
`<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Comment: @spencergibb - This still not working for me . Here is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922674/unable-to-fetch-property-value-from-the-config-server