# microservice doesn't fetch properties from spring-cloud-config-server microservice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I want to build a simple microservices app with spring cloud config server. I am using Github repository to store my configuration files. Currently, I have two very simple microservices. One of them is a cloud-config-server which retrieve properties from the remote repo on Github. In the main class of this microservice, I added @EnableConfigServer annotation and I provided a couple of properties in the application.properties file:

```
spring.application.name=cloud-config-server
server.port=8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=*Remote repo URI*
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=*Username*
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=*Password*
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
```

If I go to http://localhost:8888/cloud-config-server/default everything works well, my spring cloud config server retrieves properties successfully.

In my second microservice, I added bootstrap.properties with 2 properties to connect to the cloud-config-server:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.name=cloud-config-server
```

And I also added this dependency

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
       </dependency>
```

Unfortunately, my microservice doesn't retrieve properties from cloud-config-server. When I try to use property via @Value annotation I get an error:

*Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'test.text' in value "${test.text}*

I am sure, I didn't make a typo in my property name "test.text".

Comment: please include versions

Comment: Spring boot 2.4.0 and Spring Cloud 2020.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880039/unable-to-fetch-values-from-spring-cloud-config-server-to-my-config-clientlimit

Comment: **The solution was shared in detail here:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/66533416/10791378

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've already solved my problem. Bootstrap.properties file is no longer enabled by default. You can enable it by adding new dependency:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

or alternatively, you can remove bootstrap.properties file and provide these properties in your application.properties file

```
spring.config.import=configserver:*URI to your cloud config server*
spring.cloud.config.name=*Your cloud config server name*
```

Comment: FYI if anyone is still interested in this issue, SpringBoot 2.4 or higher recommends using the `spring.config.import` property as "the default way" instead of using *bootstrap.properties + spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap* dep. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#config-data-import) for more info.

Comment: What will be the value when we use file-system based git?

Answer (score 1):

In Client application.properties you must use not the server name, but client application name

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.name=applicationname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
```

for spring cloud and

```
<version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

for spring boot.

Also in application.properties file :

```
spring.config.cloud.uri=htp://localhost:8888
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:htp://localhost:8888
```

These should solve your problem as it did to mine.