# Spring cloud config client is not getting/loading configuration files from config server after upgrading to 2.4.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, microservices, updates

**spring-cloud-config-client** is not able to read configuration files from the **spring-cloud-config-server** after upgrading to `2.4.0` with spring-cloud version `2020.0.0-M6`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From spring-boot 2.4.0 version, bootstrapping is not enabled by default, need to add the following dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
```

or `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why would they remove it though? Been battling with for almost 4 hours

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been on this for a whole day.

Comment: @Thirumal - Can you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899388/native-profile-is-not-working-with-spring-boot-2-7-0-for-calling-service?

Answer (score 3):

**For new spring cloud versions please don't use the legacy dependency spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap instead you need to use application.yml/application.properties instead of bootstrap.yml/bootstrap.properties and then set into that file the following properties:**

```
spring:
  config:
    import: configserver:${your_config_server_url} # example: import: configserver:http://192.168.0.4:8080
  cloud:
    config:
      username: ${your_config_server_auth_user} # This is required only if your config server use authentication
      password: ${your_config_server_auth_password} # This is required only if your config server use authentication
```

Comment: How to specify the `environment`?

Comment: I used the below properties but it's not working `spring:
  application:
    name: testclient
  profiles:
    active: DEV
  config:
    import: configserver:http://192.168.0.12:8888 # example: import: configserver:http://192.168.0.4:8080
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://192.168.0.12:8888
      username: thirumal # This is required only if your config server use authentication
      password: thirumal # This is required only if your config server use authentication` Do you have any example in GIT?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the application file (.properties or .yml) the property ***spring.config.import*** , with this it is not necessary to change/add the project's dependencies

Example:
To connect to the server at the URL defined in property `spring.cloud.config.uri`, falling back to the default of "http://localhost:8888" if the property is not defined

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:
```

(remove `optional:` to have it fail if the server is not reachable)

For more info:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/#config-data-import

Comment: Dow you have any example in GIT?